# How to test service instance in CF

Tags: mongodb, ssh, cloud, cloud-foundry

I've created service instance of service from the market place e.g. instance of mongoDB and my question if I want to develop locally (on my local machine )and connect to this service instance how can I do it?

I want to test my app against created instance of backing service ,how i can do it simple ...? **Example will be very helpful**

**UPDATE:**
I try to connect to MongoDB instance which is on cloud foundry 
from my locall app.
(If I put the app I was able to connect successfully but I want to connect from my local pc i.e. run my application locally)

```
I got the following db (json) credentials:

     {
  "mongodb": [
    {
      "credentials": {
        "dbname": "CFad18ZNGYzzrrts",
        "hostname": "10.11.123.30",
        "password": "RttomuAV9yvhwHm_",
        "port": "36232",
        "ports": {
          "27017/tcp": "36232",
          "28017/tcp": "49255"
        },
        "uri": "mongodb://xppt7gdk1G9Y1pd3:RttomuAV9yvhwHm_@10.11.123.30:36232/CFad18ZNGYzzrrts",
        "username": "xppt7gdk1G9Y1pd3"
      },
      "label": "mongodb",
      "name": "mod",
      "plan": "v3.0-container",
      "provider": null,
      "syslog_drain_url": null,
      "tags": [
        "mongodb",
        "document"
      ],
      "volume_mounts": []
    },
```

**when I connect to this DB via push my I did the following which works**

```
if (process.env.VCAP_SERVICES) {
    var val = JSON.parse(process.env.VCAP_SERVICES)
    mongoose.connect(val['mongodb'][0].credentials.uri, function (err) {
```

...
Now I copy the config above to my project (under config/config.json)
and try to connect from my local app via this and its not working

```
var config = require('../config/config.json');

mongoose.connect(val['mongodb'][0].credentials.uri, function (err
```

**The error is**

```
failed to connect to server [10.11.123.30:36232] on first connect
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/Users/f53356/WebstormProjects/dlStackDemo/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:325:35)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:188:7)
```

Any idea how to over come this,
I use the URI when my app running on CF but now Im not able to run it from **my pc locally and connect to the service instance in CF**,any idea?

Comment: I've removed the ibm-bluemix tag because the OP confirmed that this question is not about Bluemix.  Which may lead to the wrong assumptions by people posting any answers.

Answer (score 0):

Ryan,

The `mongodb` service is an experimental service available in Bluemix that you can access only via a Cloud Foundry application, hence you cannot connect it from your local machine.

If you want to use a MongoDB database in Bluemix and have your application connect to it you can use the `Compose for MongoDB` service:

https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/compose-for-mongodb

Once you a create an instance of this service it will also create default credentials. You can access the credentials via VCAP_SERVICES from a Bluemix application you bind to the service or you can get the credentials via cf command line:

```
$ cf service-key your-instance-name Credentials-1
```

`Credentials-1` is the default name of the credentials when you create the Compose for MongoDB instance.

Comment: Hi Alex I try to use it against clean CF install (not bluemix for now ) which include the default services like mongo postgress redis etc , is it possible to connect to it ? if now why ?

Comment: In addition when I push my app I was able to connect to the mongodb and store data (I created new instance via cf create service....), my question is just if I run my application locally how can I connect to the service instance  (which works OK when you push the app...)

Comment: I believe this it the default configuration for cloud foundry, but I am not sure. You probably can try to configure your network to allow this access, but I don't know how to do that. You can try to create an ssh tunnel as well as described here: https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/ssh-services.html

Comment: Thanks but this is not helping , any other idea?

Comment: are you using pcfdev or bosh-lite, or some other cloudfoundry installation? I have had success connecting to service instances within pcfdev from my local station. Try connecting with your mongo command line client. If that does not work, then the firewall is blocking the connection.

Answer (score 0):

You can map an external route to your service instance with cf bind-route-service for testing with a local application, but you shouldn't do it.

It is better to have a separate development space within your CloudFoundry organisation and test/deploy everything in CF from the very early beginning.